# Add Valus of a List of Tuple if Their Corresponding First Elements are within a Specific Range

Tags: list, numpy, sum, tuples, conditional-statements

Here is my list of tuples:

```
list=[(8.0056, 1.0), (8.0269, 0.6666666666666666), (8.0302, 1.0), (8.0426, 0.3333333333333333), (8.0492, 1.0), (8.0766, 0.6666666666666666), (8.0817, 0.3333333333333333), (8.1297, 1.0), (8.137, 0.3333333333333333), (8.1778, 1.0), (8.1858, 1.0), (8.1948, 1.0), (8.2044, 0.3333333333333333), (8.2143, 0.3333333333333333), (8.3222, 0.3333333333333333), (8.3314, 0.3333333333333333), (8.3627, 0.3333333333333333), (8.3818, 0.3333333333333333), (8.436, 1.0), (8.4816, 0.6666666666666666), (8.4891, 1.0), (8.4932, 0.3333333333333333), (8.5348, 0.3333333333333333), (8.5924, 0.3333333333333333), (8.6229, 0.3333333333333333), (8.6698, 0.6666666666666666), (8.6826, 0.3333333333333333), (8.7485, 0.3333333333333333), (8.782, 1.0), (8.8158, 0.3333333333333333), (8.8382, 0.3333333333333333), (8.8708, 0.3333333333333333), (8.8737, 0.3333333333333333), (8.882, 0.3333333333333333), (9.1274, 1.0), (9.3071, 1.0), (9.3373, 1.0), (9.3564, 1.0), (9.367, 0.3333333333333333), (9.4711, 1.0), (9.5184, 1.0), (9.6954, 1.0), (9.7214, 0.3333333333333333), (9.743, 1.0), (9.8061, 0.3333333333333333), (9.9565, 0.6666666666666666), (10.0249, 0.3333333333333333), (10.0734, 0.6666666666666666), (10.0917, 0.6666666666666666), (10.2095, 1.0), (10.2967, 1.0), (10.3707, 1.0), (10.8679, 1.0), (10.9173, 1.0), (8.0022, 0.3333333333333333), (8.0504, 0.3333333333333333), (8.0527, 0.3333333333333333), (8.0645, 0.3333333333333333), (8.1836, 0.6666666666666666), (8.2122, 0.6666666666666666), (8.2433, 0.6666666666666666), (8.2849, 0.3333333333333333), (8.396, 0.3333333333333333), (8.64, 0.3333333333333333), (8.6793, 0.3333333333333333), (8.8079, 0.3333333333333333), (8.8313, 0.3333333333333333), (8.8396, 0.3333333333333333), (8.8666, 0.3333333333333333), (9.0763, 0.6666666666666666), (9.2683, 0.3333333333333333), (9.7969, 0.6666666666666666), (9.8302, 0.6666666666666666), (10.0856, 0.3333333333333333), (10.2049, 0.6666666666666666), (10.7051, 0.6666666666666666), (8.0082, 0.3333333333333333), (8.0245, 0.3333333333333333), (8.1414, 0.3333333333333333), (8.1661, 0.3333333333333333), (8.2014, 0.3333333333333333), (8.2794, 0.3333333333333333), (8.3103, 0.3333333333333333), (8.4627, 0.3333333333333333), (8.5279, 0.3333333333333333), (8.5326, 0.3333333333333333), (8.5507, 0.3333333333333333), (9.4476, 0.3333333333333333)]
```

If we name these elements as *(x, y),* I want to add all *y*'s whose *x*'s are within a specific range. This means, for example, for x to be in the range *(8.0, 8.4)*, summation should result in *17.666*.

***The answer with the shortest format (e.g. one-line) will be accepted if it turns out that there are many ways to do it.**

---

Here is my best try:

```
dm=0.4
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
for item in list:
    if (8. +  0*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  1*dm):
        item1 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  1*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  2*dm):
        item2 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  2*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  3*dm):
        item3 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  3*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  4*dm):
        item4 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  4*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  5*dm):
        item5 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  5*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  6*dm):
        item6 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  6*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  7*dm):
        item7 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  7*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  8*dm):
        item8 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  8*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  9*dm):
        item9 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  9*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  10*dm):
        item10 += item[1]
    elif (8. +  10*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  11*dm):
        item11 += item[1]

y_values = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11]

print(y_values)
```

Here is output:

```
[17.666666666666664, 8.333333333333332, 4.666666666666667, 6.0, 4.666666666666666, 5.666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 2.0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

One line is tough, but two is doable

```
>>> label, data = np.array(the_list).T
>>> np.bincount((8 + 0.4 * np.arange(12)).searchsorted(label), data, 12)
array([ 0.        , 17.66666667,  8.33333333,  4.66666667,  6.        ,
        4.66666667,  5.66666667,  0.66666667,  2.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ])
```